# using rangeOfString and textfield shouldChangeCharactersInRange - the delete character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, textfield

I'm using rangeofString and textfield: shouldChangeCharactersinRange: to restrict the types of keystrokes that will be valid in a textfield.

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


    NSString *includeString = @"1234567890-()+" ;

    if ([includeString rangeOfString:string].location == NSNotFound) {
        return NO;
    }

return YES;
```

}

this works fine EXCEPT i now can't use the delete key. Any ideas how to represent the delete key to add it to the includeString?

I tried

`NSString *includeString = @"1234567890-()+\b"

but that didn't work - neither did it allow the \ or b characters to appear which i thought odd

Thanks

Comment: The special escape sequence `\b` gets converted to the backspace character by the compiler. A user can't enter a backspace character. When user deletes text, the replacement string is simply empty. This is why `\b` doesn't work and why you can't enter a backslash or a `b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The replacement string `string` is *empty* when characters are deleted.
Since `rangeOfString:string` returns `NSNotFound` for an empty string,
you have to check for that situation first:

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if ([string length] == 0)
        return YES;
    NSString *includeString = @"1234567890-()+" ;
    if ([includeString rangeOfString:string].location == NSNotFound) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**Update:** As @rmaddy correctly pointed out, the above method fails if more than one
character is *pasted* into the text field. The following method checks if *all*
characters of the replacement string are valid. (There are probably many solutions,
this is only one of them.)

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    static NSString *includeString = @"1234567890-()+";
    NSCharacterSet *includeSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:includeString];
    if ([[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:includeSet] length] > 0)
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Note that the empty string does not need to be handled separately anymore.

Comment: Keep in mind that this code (nor the original) will not work properly if a user pastes in text containing more than one character even if all of the pasted characters are valid.

Comment: @rmaddy: You are right! I had focused only on the "delete" part and not thought about it thoroughly. Thank you for the correction, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Great answer. Making `includeString` local static might be even better. BTW, you also may need `\n` to make sure your `Done` button works, i.e. dismisses the keyboard.

Comment: @Schultz9999: Thanks for the feedback and the suggestion. I have updated the answer accordingly. I will test the newline/Done issue later.